# What is banking compliance

Tags: economic-terms, law

I'm not sure if I'm using the term correctly but there's something that's referred to as *compliance in banking*. Am I correct to understand that it's the process of obeying the laws and regulatory guidelines for financial institutions in general? Or is there a more specific meaning to the term?

What would be two or three common examples of such compliances?

Answer (score 2):

**You are using it correctly**. It means the processes and protocols created by banks or those imposed to them by authorities. If the bank also has some quality certificate, like iSOs, them this imposes new compliance costs and processes.

Comment: Would you mind giving a few examples that are commonly enforced? I can think of flagging deposits over x units, request to provide proof of how cash is obtained and blocking transactions with international banks that might be loose on the obedience.